# How to get a domain with invalid contact details

Tags: domains, domain-registration

There's a domain that I want. The registrant details were hidden behind Domain Discreet, which no longer exists, and none of the contact info works, email bounces etc. so I can't approach the owner and ask what they want for it. It was due to expire last year so I used a deleting domains provider to try and grab it, but several months after it was supposed to have expired it was re-registered by its current owner for another two years. Tried filing a complaint with ICANN about the invalid contact details but no dice. Advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File a complaint with the actual company that registered the domain as well, not just ICANN.. They will have his billing adress and a working email to notify them that they have to update their who.is info.

I would also keep filing complaints to ICANN every so often.

Comment: I'm on my 2nd ICANN complaint, will proceed with complaining to the registrar too.

Answer (score 0):

If you really-really want it, create a "I want the yourWantedDomain" page and make it go viral - might reach the current owner. 
Create another viral content and mention somewhere there that you want to contact them in order to obtain the domain. That's what I'd do if I wanted the domain so badly.
If not, can't think of any option; using aardvark to ask who the owner is maybe? (http://vark.com/)

Comment: What button can I click to *make* my page go viral?  /sarcasm

Comment: I didn't say it's easy, and I said to go that way if it's really-really important = crucial to get. If you want _your_page to go viral or better, you might want to check the "Contact us" button here: http://www.spheri.ca/ - but I've heard it's kind of expensive.

Comment: No offence intended, @qes , but while you find my answer inappropriate, why don't you come up with a better idea? Maybe it's not a perfect answer, but if several different answers (which might not be individually perfect) gather, a perfect solution based on those might come up. I have no problem whatsoever with accepting criticism, but in this situation I'd find it more constructive if accompanied by a better solution.